# Is this integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(a x+ 2b \arctan x)}{x^2+1}dx$ exactly zero when $b\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, conjectures

I recently encountered this integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(a x+ 2b \arctan x)}{x^2+1}dx$$
which suspiciously close to 0 for nonzero integer values of $b$, as indicated by numerical calculations. When $b$ is not an integer it is not 0. Based on my experiments I conjecture that
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(a x+ 2b \arctan x)}{x^2+1}dx=0,~~~~b\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}.$$

> **Question.** Is the above conjecture true?

Comment: So did you apply $cos(A+B)$?

Comment: @Mason and then what? There will be a sum of 2 integrals that doesn't seem to be easier to handle.

Comment: Also I am not sure that contour-integration is an appropriate tag.

Comment: Then partial fraction decomp and/or you have sin(arctan() and cos(arctan()) and there might be some good stuff that happens there.

Comment: @Mason who knows? If after someone posts an answer and it will turn out that the integral can not be tackled by countour integration I will remove the tag.

Comment: @Mason frankly I don't know. Notice that we have $cos(2b*arctan())$, not just  $cos(arctan())$.

Comment: If we take $u=\arctan(x)$

Then we have $ \int_0^{\pi/2} cos(a \tan(u)+bu) du$
where $a \tan$ means $a \times \tan()$

Comment: It must be $2bu$, but else the transformation is correct. I have tried different values for $a$ and $b$ via WolframAlpha, and it always (and quickly!) yields $0$ if $b$ is an integer, so I suppose there must indeed be some transformation to simplify the integral.

Comment: @Tyrell See my comment below the partial answer by Thern. The numerical evidence that $a$ and $b$ must be of the same sign suggests that contour integral (or at least complex expression) is relevant. It is common in contour integral or Fourier transform to see the dependence on the sign.

Comment: @Mason Note that the original integrand is even in $x$. After your $u = \arctan x$ one can extend the integration limit to $ u = -\pi/2 \sim \pi/2$. Not sure if this allows more approaches.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can, as the author suspected, be approached by contour integration.

Let $a>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. As Mason pointed out, the integral in question is equal to
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(a\tan(x)+2nx)dx$$
Using that the integrand is even we may extend the bounds to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ then perform the substitution $t=2x$ to find this is
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(a\tan(t/2)+nt)dt$$
Notice that this is is equal to
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(ia\tan(t/2)+int)dt$$
since the odd part of $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ cancels. Now by expanding the tangent in terms of exponentials and performing some algebra we find 
$$\tan(t/2)=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{it}-1}{e^{it}+1}$$
Thus we may rewrite our integral as a contour integral with $z=e^{i t}$, $dt=\frac{1}{iz}dz$. Since our bounds are $t\in(-\pi,\pi)$, the contour is the unit circle. Thus our integral is 
$$\frac{1}{4i}\oint \exp(a\frac{z-1}{z+1})z^{n-1}dz$$
(Notice $e^{int}=z^n$.) By the Residue Theorem, this contour integral is equal to
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ Res}_{z=0} \exp(a\frac{z-1}{z+1})z^{n-1}$$
This residue is the coefficient of $z^{-n}$ in $\exp(a\frac{z-1}{z+1})$. Since this function is analytic inside the unit disk, this coefficient is $0$ for $n>0$ (with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$). The value of the integral for negative integral $n$ is given by the $|n|$th Taylor coefficient of $\frac{\pi}{2}\exp(a\frac{z-1}{z+1})$.

Comment: Well done. Note that if $a$ and $n$ are negative, we can return to positive values of both because $\cos(-x)=cos(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not a full answer, but part of the way:

Let $a=0$. Then we have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(0+ 2b \arctan x)}{x^2+1}dx=\left[\frac{\sin\left(2b \arctan(x)\right)}{2b}\right]_0^\infty\\
=\frac{\sin\left(2b\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2b}-\frac{\sin(2b\cdot0)}{2b}\\
= \frac{\sin(b\pi)}{2b}$$

This is obviously zero if and only if b is an integer (except zero).

Currently I am not fully aware why this behavior remains when $a\neq0$, maybe I find a solution for that later on.

Comment: I'd like to point out that: only when the sign of $a$ and $b$ are the same can the conjecture be true. For example [this is not zero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B++Divide%5BCos%5B1.1+x+-+6+ArcTan@x%5D,+x%5E2+%2B+1%5D,+%7Bx,+0,+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D+&wal=header) but [this is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B++Divide%5BCos%5B-1.1+x+-+6+ArcTan@x%5D,+x%5E2+%2B+1%5D,+%7Bx,+0,+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D) zero.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $a > 0$ and that $n$ is a positive integer.

We have

$$ \begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(ax  + 2 n \arctan x \right)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp \left(i\left( ax + 2n \arctan x\right) \right)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} \, \frac{ \exp \left(n \log(1+ix) - n\log(1-ix)  \right)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} \, \frac{(1+ix)^{n}}{(1-ix)^{n}(1+x^{2})} \, \mathrm dx \\ &=  \frac{1}{2}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} \,  \frac{(1+ix)^{n-1}}{(1-ix)^{n+1}} \, \mathrm dx.  \end{align}$$

Let's integrate the function $$\ e^{iaz} \, \frac{(1+iz)^{n-1}}{(1-iz)^{n+1}} $$ around the semicircular contour $[-R, R] \cup Re^{i[0,\pi] } $.

Since $n$ is a positive integer, the function is analytic in the upper half of the complex plane.

And by Jordan's lemma (or the estimation lemma) the integral vanishes along the semicircle as $R \to \infty$.

Therefore, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} \,  \frac{(1+ix)^{n-1}}{(1-ix)^{n+1}} \, \mathrm dx =0, $$ and the result follows.

---

$(1)$ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html (1)